# please help with null exception when adding data with grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am trying to add data to a database, in grails but get this error:

Error 500: Executing action [getData] of controller [mgr.CollectDataEntryController] caused exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.addToAlumConnectionEducations() is applicable for argument types: (mgr.AlumConnectionEducations) values: [mgr.AlumConnectionEducations : null]

where CollectDataEntryController is the controller doing the work.  here is the code snippet from that controller:

```
saveNewAlum.addToAlumConnectionEducations(new AlumConnectionEducations(alumConnectionsId:connectionId, degree:alumConnectionEduDegree,endDate:alumConnectionEduEndDate,fieldOfStdudy:alumConnectionEduFieldOfStudy,schoolName:alumConnectionEduSchoolName,startDate:alumConnectionEduStartDate))
```

the domain, AlumConnectionEducations , belongs to a one to many relationship with another domain, AlumConnections, which in turn belongs to a one-to-many relationship with to another domain, alumProfile

to, in my code I first add the domain AlumConnection, which works fine but when i then try to add AlumConnectionEducations i get the above error.  anyone have any idea of what i am doing wrong?

thanks
jason

```
    package mgr
    import java.util.Date;
    class AlumConnections  {
String linkedinId
String firstName
String lastName
String headline
String locationName
String locationCode
String industry
    Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
long version
static belongsTo = [alumProfile:AlumProfile]
static hasMany = [  
alumConnectionEducations    :   AlumConnectionEducations
 ]
static mapping = {
    cache true

    columns {       
        linkedinId      type:'text'
        firstName       type:'text'
        lastName        type:'text'
        headline        type:'text'
        locationName    type:'text'
        locationCode    type:'text'
        industry        type:'text'

    }
}
static constraints = {  
    linkedinId      (nullable:false, blank:false)
    firstName       (nullable:true)
    lastName        (nullable:true)
    headline        (nullable:true)
    locationName    (nullable:true)
    locationCode    (nullable:true)
    industry        (nullable:true)

}
  }
```

in the controller that calls the domains:

```
  def saveNewAlum = ""
  saveNewAlum = new AlumProfile(firstName:linkedinFirstName, lastName:linkedinLastName, dob:newDate,industry:linkedinIndustry, oAuthToken:oAuthtoken, secretKey:secretKey)

  saveNewAlum.addToAlumConnections(new   AlumConnections(linkedinId:connectionId,firstName:connectionFName, lastName:connectionLName, headline:connectionHeadline, locationName:connectionLocationname, locationCode:connectionLocationCode,industry:connectionIndustry))
```

The above code works fine and saves to the MySQL database.  its only when i try to create  saveNewAlum.addToAlumConnectionEducations that i get the error

Comment: Can you post your code for AlumConnections?

Comment: i added it to my above question, as i couldnt seem to add it in a comment.

Comment: Can you also add the code that creates the `saveNewAlum` variable? Have you verified that it's truly an instance of `AlumConnections`?

Comment: thank you for your reply.  i added the saveNewAlum code to the first post.  yes, i have verified that the saveNewAlum works fine as it saves to the MySQL db without error

Comment: maybe whats wrong is this:  i have a one-to-many relationship.  to save it, i first create the parent (saveNewAlum) then, to add its various children (those objects that belong to it) i  do this: saveNewAlum.addToAlumConnections(new   AlumConnections(...)) but the problem is that i need to know how to take one of the children and create a one-to-many with it and another object (alumConnectionEducations).  So, would i have to do something like this:  saveNewAlum.AlumConnections.addToAlumConnectionEducations(new   AlumConnections.Educations(...)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it took all day but i got it.  so, my assumption seemed to be right, it was the one-to-many with a one-to-many that was causing the problem.  here's how i fixed it.  The domains were right the way i had it.  in the controller:
first, i create the main parent:

```
         saveNewAlum=new AlumProfile(firstName:linkedinFirstName, lastName:linkedinLastName, dob:newDate, industry:linkedinIndustry, oAuthToken:oAuthtoken, secretKey:secretKey)
```

then, i create the object to be added to the child:

```
     myConnection= new AlumConnections(linkedinId:connectionId,firstName:connectionFName,lastName:connectionLName,headline:connectionHeadline,locationName:connectionLocationname, locationCode:connectionLocationCode,industry:connectionIndustry)
```

then, i save the child to the parent:

```
    saveNewAlum.addToAlumConnections(myConnection)
```

then, i create the object to save to the child's child:

```
  newConnectionEdu=  new AlumConnectionEducations(
              degree:alumConnectionEduDegree,
              endDate:alumConnectionEduEndDate,
              fieldOfStudy:alumConnectionEduFieldOfStudy,
              schoolName:alumConnectionEduSchoolName,
              startDate:alumConnectionEduStartDate)
```

then, finally, i add the child to the child:

```
 myConnection.addToAlumConnectionEducations(newConnectionEdu)
```

and that is how you add a child to a child!

Comment: you may also play around cascading for same.